# post hoc test using emmeans in R

Tags: r, emmeans

I am trying to do the posthoc test using emmeans with the unequal size data, we have 81 data for 2017 and 2018 while 54 for 2019 and 2020.
when I run:

```r
n1<-lm(production~Forage* Dep* Region*Year,data = productiondata)
Anova(n1, type = "III")
```

it tells me there is a significant Year term, so i will do

```r
n1.emm<-emmeans(n1,~Year)
multcomp::cld(n1.emm,Letters = c("cba", LETTERS, letters))
```

but it gives me

```r
#>      Year emmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>      2018  0.202 0.0292 180    0.144    0.260  c    
#>      2017  0.316 0.0292 180    0.258    0.374   b   
#>      2019 nonEst     NA  NA       NA       NA       
#>      2020 nonEst     NA  NA       NA       NA   .
```

Is it because unbalanced sample size? or can i just analysis the data 2017 and 2018 first, then analysis the 2019 and 2020

Here is part of the data from 2017 to 2020, factors including forage types, slope positions (Dep) and slope locations (Region).

```r
productiondata<-tibble::tribble(
                  ~Forage, ~Rep,           ~Dep, ~Region,  ~production, ~Year,
                     "CM",   1L, "Middle slope", "Front",   -0.0757967, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.383363317, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",   0.20031297, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.102828226, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.137751896, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.186359699, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.293134779, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L, "Middle slope",  "Back", -0.056145226, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.110055295, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.405797312, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.419412779, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.175870014, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.021058595, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.457371004, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.176926709, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.312558379, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.237850393, 2017L,
                     "SF",   1L, "Middle slope",  "Back",   0.27376153, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.650740692, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L, "Middle slope", "Front",  1.188104115, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.395448203, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.424295545, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.164290731, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",   0.40816997, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.111238888, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.566095643, 2017L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.918502747, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L, "Middle slope", "Front",   0.17000103, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.124995501, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.361056138, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.154110887, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.135812322, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.220526988, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  1.594788865, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.123220876, 2017L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.171494657, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.811326188, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.334850017, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",   0.30377977, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.340343281, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  1.191563294, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.494175439, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.138654458, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.254369827, 2017L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  1.176311982, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.178139174, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.148593992, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.328471488, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.141711479, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.194340209, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.254543786, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.315270823, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.378577187, 2017L,
                     "SF",   3L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.166886561, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",   0.03738448, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.108509969, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.237387653, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.247917218, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.851589071, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.451171536, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.404444632, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.301760361, 2017L,
                     "BM",   1L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.127860314, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.383069727, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.070114468, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.303749951, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.133379368, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.358519177, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid", -0.007763312, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.239034374, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.115579213, 2017L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.349689868, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.102937676, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.144631271, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.555076095, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.139111419, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.112648071, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.419909989, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.125487985, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.132989815, 2017L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.360532331, 2017L,
                     "CM",   1L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.823211913, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.059252546, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",    0.2668649, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.415384275, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.230051318, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.035898999, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.056801122, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.089305575, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",    0.1279251, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.155458955, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.157681983, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.289525022, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.148003016, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.186071161, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.159468549, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.208308319, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.033821257, 2018L,
                     "SF",   1L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.090729548, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.220152331, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.345553942, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.183422931, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.337881801, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.191016098, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.066807322, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.156634854, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L, "Middle slope",  "Back",   0.33147729, 2018L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.507778602, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.142964156, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.217805981, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front", -0.016447569, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.088735853, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.067023826, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.090222322, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.755210356, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.033353859, 2018L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.069316483, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.285738823, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.145161028, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.496575473, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.113559597, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.313790171, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.074363169, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.043558845, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.150449662, 2018L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.302758471, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.217500707, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.063166278, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.226241436, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.058145798, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.726712925, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.076343082, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back", -0.020454532, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.135020917, 2018L,
                     "SF",   3L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.126201005, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.006827447, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.030791791, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.113347236, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.612115531, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.823126575, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.164988931, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.290850698, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",   0.06402747, 2018L,
                     "BM",   1L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.018032821, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  1.255409991, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.162279939, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.090145577, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",   0.08920931, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.160615406, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.005158395, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",    0.0579296, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.102417402, 2018L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.133730268, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.108384772, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L, "Middle slope", "Front",  0.061884038, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.452165338, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.023610281, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L, "Middle slope",   "Mid",  0.054681945, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.162076608, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",   0.06616292, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L, "Middle slope",  "Back",  0.184195079, 2018L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.206608544, 2018L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.772985983, 2019L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.364508409, 2019L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.243149558, 2019L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.215994088, 2019L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.112061649, 2019L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.438087275, 2019L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.750599185, 2019L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.267425896, 2019L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",   0.19840739, 2019L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.176529734, 2019L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.236722914, 2019L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.236223726, 2019L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.635134498, 2019L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.372211427, 2019L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.199820419, 2019L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",   0.46113438, 2019L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.660912878, 2019L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",   0.11447776, 2019L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.294450859, 2019L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.414679886, 2019L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.234473286, 2019L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.081707982, 2019L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.147330437, 2019L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.292489546, 2019L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.769036534, 2019L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",   0.84546713, 2019L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  1.041736495, 2019L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.190840896, 2019L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.306522586, 2019L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.134396212, 2019L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.490252306, 2019L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  1.139213653, 2019L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.391245366, 2019L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.138360718, 2019L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.203979966, 2019L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.999057722, 2019L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.530290061, 2019L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.530824288, 2019L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.147126674, 2019L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.110059696, 2019L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.359837115, 2019L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  1.046260797, 2019L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.411154363, 2019L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.372156901, 2019L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.127483022, 2019L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.164251999, 2019L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.607006353, 2019L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.264008902, 2019L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.200614369, 2019L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.198312215, 2019L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.310858137, 2019L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.193117494, 2019L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.230430021, 2019L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.196167434, 2019L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.409807334, 2020L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  1.151073187, 2020L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",     0.623391, 2020L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.441892889, 2020L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.238760633, 2020L,
                     "CM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.722932125, 2020L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.232819693, 2020L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.400936867, 2020L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.638681473, 2020L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.642732415, 2020L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.176816275, 2020L,
                     "SF",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.671645947, 2020L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.490810627, 2020L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.586205959, 2020L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.511576498, 2020L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.703077531, 2020L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",   0.85734072, 2020L,
                     "CM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.268919641, 2020L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",   0.17324176, 2020L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.590438961, 2020L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.500350299, 2020L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.333574034, 2020L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.282617746, 2020L,
                     "SF",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.624364392, 2020L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.117128287, 2020L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.509984274, 2020L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.715619382, 2020L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",   0.33634171, 2020L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.394804475, 2020L,
                     "CM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.381536229, 2020L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.562928257, 2020L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.843107099, 2020L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.873072304, 2020L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.300811764, 2020L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.773220048, 2020L,
                     "SF",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  1.499352448, 2020L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.356242766, 2020L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.912103296, 2020L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.206597753, 2020L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope", "Front",   0.30611503, 2020L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",  0.479452565, 2020L,
                     "BM",   1L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",   0.98084807, 2020L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.379028643, 2020L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.490640158, 2020L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.178256036, 2020L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",  0.498560885, 2020L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.445660456, 2020L,
                     "BM",   2L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",    0.3503611, 2020L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",   "Mid",  0.386290635, 2020L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope", "Front",  0.569205127, 2020L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope", "Front",  0.719400452, 2020L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",   "Mid",    0.5179629, 2020L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Upper slope",  "Back",   0.41695316, 2020L,
                     "BM",   3L,  "Lower slope",  "Back",  0.840314197, 2020L
                  )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: No, I don't think unequal sample size would cause `emmeans` to not calculate a marginal mean. I would say something else is going on, but without a reproducible example it's impossible to tell what.

Comment: I agree with Axeman. Can you share your dataset or - even better - create a `reprex` https://reprex.tidyverse.org/#usage with your data https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html ?

Comment: Hi, I made some edits and attach part of the data, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emmeans()` checks for estimability, and will not show output for non-estimable cases because, well, they can't be estimated, at least uniquely. The model isn't shown here, but my best guess is that there are at least two interacting factors, and that there is no data for some factor combinations.

Which brings up another issue. If `Year` is involved in interactions with other factors, you probably shouldn't average over those other factors because the interactions imply that the effects depend on the levels of those other factors. An advisory message to that effect is printed, and it is not shown either. People really shouldn't ignore warnings.

If the interactions amount to anything, you should not be doing those marginal comparisons. If the interactions are negligible, then re-fit the model without them, and the estimability issues will probably go away.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, so when I run n1<-lm(production~Forage* Dep* Region*Year,data = productiondata), if there isn't a significant term, do I have to change it into n1<-lm(production~Forage+ Dep+ Region+Year,data = productiondata) and run again?

Comment: You have 11 interactions in this model. Which ones have small P values? Don't take those out of the model. Do any of them involve Year? If so, don't do marginal means for Year, but separate ones for each level (or combinations of levels) of factors it interacts with

Comment: Again, thanks for the help, but before that, if I meet a situation that, the assumption was violated: the model residual was significantly not normal, and even after the log transform it didn't get any better, then what should I do

Comment: We are straying further and further from what is intended with StackOverflow. I actually suggest that you find a statistical consultant. Most statistics and biostatistics departments have a way of connecting you with one.